# GCM XMPP server authentication

Tags: android, python, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement googls example of GCM server as discribed here: 
[Writing the Server Code](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server)

and i'm getting the following error:

```
DEBUG: socket       sent  <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="PLAIN">...</auth>
DEBUG: socket       error Socket error while receiving data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 146, in receive
    try: received = self._recv(BUFLEN)
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:1325: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
DEBUG: socket       error Socket operation failed
Authentication failed!
```

My server is behind a NAT and firewall. I've opened a rule for outgoing connection to ANY and forwarded ports 5228-5230, as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#server). Though, because of resources issues I can't  forward all ports to the server, neither 80 or 443.

Any ideas on what causing this error and can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: often SSL errors with xmpppy are caused by the fact that xmpppy is really old. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37017182/267540

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's your only problem, but you opened the wrong ports :

> GCM Cloud Connection Server (CCS) is an XMPP endpoint, running on http://gcm.googleapis.com port **5235**.

The ports that you opened are only required for your Android device to receive messages from the GCM server when your device is connected to the internet via WiFi :

> Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM **in order for your Android devices to receive messages**. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.

Comment: I did so and unfortunately it didn't work, still got this error.
I also tied to sniff packets from the server and the gateway, it doesn't seems like this error caused by packet loss.