# GCM Notifications with Python XMPP

Tags: android, python, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

Google provides a python [code sample](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) for sending GCM notifications using the Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP). The guide doesn't specifically mention where the '`import xmpp`' comes from. However this tallies closely with [xmpppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/).

Unfortunately this xmpppy project seems to have been abandoned many years ago. The last release was in 2009. No wonder that there incompatibilities with current versions of openssl

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_ccs.py", line 54, in <module>
    client.connect(server=(SERVER,PORT), secure=1, use_srv=False)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenv-django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/client.py", line 200, in connect
    if not CommonClient.connect(self,server,proxy,secure,use_srv) or secure<>None and not secure: return self.connected
  File "/usr/local/virtualenv-django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/client.py", line 178, in connect
    transports.TLS().PlugIn(self,now=1)
  File "/usr/local/virtualenv-django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 281, in PlugIn
    if now: return self._startSSL()
  File "/usr/local/virtualenv-django18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xmpp/transports.py", line 316, in _startSSL
    tcpsock._sslIssuer = tcpsock._sslObj.issuer()
AttributeError: '_ssl._SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'issuer'
```

This particular stacktrace was on Amazon Linux (Sept 2015 release). openssl-1.0.1k-14.89.amzn1.x86_64. It can also be seen on other distros. In fact a nearly identical stacktrace can be seen in other projects that have xmpppy as a dependency. How can this be solved?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/winster/xmppgcm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is to patch `xmpp/transports.py` the patch comes from [free-bsd](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/master/net-im/py-xmpppy/files/patch-xmpp-transports.py) but works on linux.

The second solution is to switch to a [fork of xmpppy](https://github.com/ArchipelProject/xmpppy) that does not have this issue. You can install it as follows.

```
source /myvirtualenv/bin/activate/
pip uninstall xmpppy
wget https://github.com/ArchipelProject/xmpppy/archive/master.zip
tar -xvf master
cd xmpppy-master

python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Now the SSL error goes disappears. You can be happy with the knowledge that you are using code that was last updated 2 years ago instead of seven years ago! This solution works for any project that has xmpppy as a dependency and isn't just limited to GCM.

Both solutions were discovered in an [Eventlet bug report](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/124).

update: 
You can even use pip to install the fork.

```
pip install https://github.com/ArchipelProject/xmpppy/archive/master.zip
```